# How to add only the postal code field to the user registration page?

Tags: users

I have a custom template file successfully rendering the user account creation page. I am using the [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location) Module, which adds a field (which appears to be a field group) to the user. I want to add **only** the postal code field (zip Code) to the user registration page.

`template.php` code:

```
    function responsive_bartik_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  $items['user_register_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-register-form',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_register_form'
    ),
  );
  $items['user_pass'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-pass',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_pass'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

`user-register-form.tpl.php` code:

```
<div class="responsive_bartik-user-pass-form-wrapper">
<?php
     print render($form['account']['name']);
     print render($form['account']['mail']);
     print render($form['account']['pass']);
     print render($form['captcha']);
     print drupal_render($form['actions']);
     print render($form["form_build_id"]); 
     print drupal_render($form['form_token']); 
     print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
?>

<p>
   <a href="password">Forgot Password</a>
</p>
<p>Already have an account?<a href="login"> Log in</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this module [Postal Code](https://www.drupal.org/project/postal_code) they can allow to only add postal code in user page

> A very minimal D7 Postal Code (ZIP Code) field with validation for one
>   country or a combination of countries

Comment: but postal code doesnt tie into other stuff, like location module or drupal commerce, or search api in the same way. Also, other fields like a detailed address will be needed later on, once user creates their account.

Comment: then you can use address field module for this purpose

Comment: I tried installing that module, but there is no configuration for it. Do i need to other modules to get it to work?

Comment: what you mean there is no configuration do you used devel module

Comment: Ok so with the Address Field Module, What code do i Type to only get the postal code on the account creation page?

Comment: add a in user registration page and get field value using devel module after that render it on your tpl file

Comment: Here is my devel line of the page. Please, in detail tell me what i would add to my custom template. field_address (Array, 17 elements)

    #type (String, 9 characters ) container
    $...['content']['system_main']['field_address']['#type']